# Rewrite Site without losing backlinks

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, seo

I recently rewrote a website that was in classic asp to asp.net. This site has a large amount of backlinks pointing to articles that end in .asp. Given that all of these articles now reside on .aspx pages how would you go about recouping those precious backlinks?

EDIT - Backlinks meaning there are a lot of other sites on the web pointing back to, for example, article.asp and article.asp will no longer exist, it will now be article.aspx.

Comment: There are many ways you can create link in asp.net. For static link html <a> tag and for dynamic link you can use Hyperlink, Link Button etc. It is hard to suggest anything without knowing how you want them to work. Provide some code/markup with links, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use URL rewriting to redirect the links appropriately - which means that they should be 301 redirects. So if someone or *something* (i.e. a search bot) visits a .asp page they will get redirected to the appropriate .aspx page instead. For IIS start here: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Ideally I'd get rid of the .aspx extension too which routing will help you with.

Answer (score 1):

I recently went through a similar project, and what we did was create a lot of placeholder pages for the old classic asp pages that looked like this:

```
<%
   Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
   Response.AddHeader "Location","/New/Page/RelativeAddress"
   Response.End
%>
```

That was the entire content of the page, such that the old page is mapped to a new location. This worked for us because I'm at a small college where I could get cheap workstudy labor to do what was basically copy/paste work. If you have a lot of pages, you could also put the map in a database table and write code into your 404 handler to do the redirect.

Comment: The key question is whether there is a 1 to 1 mapping from old to new - if there is then a simple rewrite rule should solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Here are my suggestions

1. Write a script that opens every file you have as a string, parses it and changes .asp to .aspx (takes 30min)
2. Create .asp redirect pages to redirect to your .aspx pages (also can be automated with a script)

I don't code in ASP so I don't know if there is an easier way

Answer (score -1):

one thing you can do is add simple JavaScript, use jQuery find all links end with .asp, replace with .aspx.

And add code to layout page, so it will apply to all pages.

```
<html>
<head>

     <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");</script>

</head>
<body>

    <a href="a.asp">A</a> | 
    <a href="b.asp">B</a>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[href$=".asp"]').each(function(){
            var lnk = $(this).attr('href');
            $(this).attr('href',lnk+'x')
        });

    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If possible, please add code to increase the value of your answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to keep the .asp, then you should rewrite urls in the new website (with .aspx extension) to .asp extensions. (This only applies if the structure of the link is the same in the new website with the old one)

Comment: Yes, rewrite but no not aspx to asp - t'other way round